# React Hooks: Idiomatic way to ensure that useEffect runs only when the contents of an array argument to the custom hook change

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I am creating a custom hook in React which sets up an event listener for a given set of events. A default set of events exists, and the consumer of this custom hook is not expected to customize these in the majority of use-cases. Generally, I want the event listeners to be added upon the mounting of a component and removed upon its un-mounting. However, adhering to the principles of hooks (and the `eslint(react-hooks/exhaustive-deps)` lint rule), I wish to gracefully handle changes to the list of events to watch. What is the most idiomatic way to achieve this with React hooks?

Assuming I would simply like to remove all event listeners and re-add them when the list of events changes, I could attempt the following:

```js
const useEventWatcher = (
  interval = 5000,
  events = ['mousemove', 'keydown', 'wheel']
) => {
  const timerIdRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    const resetInterval = () => {
      if (timerIdRef.current) {
        clearInterval(timerIdRef.current);
      }

      timerIdRef.current = setInterval(() => { 
        console.log(`${interval} milliseconds passed with no ${events.join(', ')} events!`);
      }, interval)
    };

    events.forEach(event => window.addEventListener(event, resetInterval));

    // Don't want to miss the first time the interval passes without
    // the given events triggering (cannot run the effect after every render due to this!)
    resetInterval();

    return () => {
      events.forEach(event => window.removeEventListener(event, resetInterval));
    };
  }, [events, interval]);
}
```

Unfortunately, this will not function as intended. Note that I would like to provide a default value for the `events` parameter. Doing that with the current approach means that `events` points to a different reference every time the custom hook runs, which means the effect runs every time as well (due to shallow dependency comparison). Ideally, I would like a way of having the effect depend on the contents of the array, rather than the reference. What is the best way of achieving this?

Comment: why do you want to avoid listing `events` in deps?  if user finally wanted to specify events it could be a big surprise that changing `['scroll']` to `['click']` processes wrong event. is not it better to handle such a case for free?

Comment: See my edit for a clarification.

Answer (score 0):

You can separate two side effects in two different `useEffects`.

1. You can run the initial `resetInterval` in the first `useEffect` on load.
   You need to run it once, and you might use a dependency of `[]`.
   But then, you need to extract `resetInterval` outside the `useEffect`.
   Another problem is that, now `resetInterval` is re-created during every render.
   So you can wrap it in `useCallback`.
   The first `useEffect` depends on `resetInterval` (which causes the `useEffect` run once on load, thus will call `resetInterval`)
2. Now you can subscribe all `events` in the second `useEffect` with dependencies on `[events, interval, resetInterval]` as suggested by "eslint(react-hooks/exhaustive-deps) lint rule".

The result would look like following &
You can check the working demo on CodeSandbox.
[image: Edit so.answer.57227862]

```js
    const useEventWatcher = (
      interval = 2000,
      events = ["mousemove", "keydown", "wheel"]
    ) => {
      const timerIdRef = useRef();

      const resetInterval = useCallback(() => {
        if (timerIdRef.current) {
          clearInterval(timerIdRef.current);
        }

        timerIdRef.current = setInterval(() => {
          console.log(
            `${interval} seconds passed with no ${events.join(", ")} events!`
          );
        }, interval);
      }, [events, interval]);

      useEffect(() => {
        resetInterval();
      }, [resetInterval]);

      useEffect(() => {
        events.forEach(event => window.addEventListener(event, resetInterval));

        return () => {
          events.forEach(event => window.removeEventListener(event, resetInterval));
        };
      }, [events, interval, resetInterval]);
    };
```

Check out the working page (I set the interval to 2 seconds for demo purpose)

When you move the mouse around, scroll wheels or press keys, the console log won't appear. Once those events are not fired, then you will see the console log messages.

[image: working demo]

Answer (score 0):

So we need to include `events` into deps but for sure we don't want endless render loop.

Option #1: use `JSON.stringify` or similar to pass string as dependency not an array

```
function useEventWatcher(events = ['click'])
useEffect(() => {
}, [JSON.stringifiy(events.sort())])
```

However ESLint will still complain so either suppress it or use de-stringify:

```
const eventsStringified = JSON.stringify(events.sort());
useEffect(() => {
 const eventsUnstringified = JSON.parse(eventsStringified);
}, [eventStringified]);
```

Option #2: move setting default value into `useMemo`. So default values will be referentially the same while `events` parameter is not passed(so it is `undefined`)

```
function useEventWatcher(events) {
const eventsOrDefault = useMemo(() => eventsPassed || ['click'], [events]);

useEffect(() => {
}, [eventsOrDefault]);
}
```